# Looking for assistance in creating similar functionality for importing and mapping a CSV, similar to Mailchimp

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import, mailchimp

What I'm attempting to do is upload a CSV of products and get the headers and create a mapping tool that will allow the user to match the CSV headers with fields they need to be imported into. I'm thinking I need to grab the column values as opposed to row values.

Mailchimp currently has this very cool functionality, as I'm sure all the other big players in email marketing do. Once imported, the system lists each column name and allows the user to select what to map it to with their built-in columns.

I've researched several different pre-existing solutions which all seemed to be buggy, and I'm simply going to have to create my own custom solution.

I'm currently utilizing PHP/MySQL. Any assistance or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a brief example of what the CSV looks like?

Just to clarify, are you trying to take a CSV and "map" (insert) all its data into a MySQL table where the user has explicitly defined the matching CSV headers and database columns?

Comment: Hi Shane, thanks for the reply. The CSV is pretty standard, for about 12 column headers and various data types for each cell. To answer your question, I'd like an intermediate step after the user uploads the CSV to where they can pick what table each column of data from the CSV goes to. Then submits it for insertion to database. I hope this answers your question thoroughly. I attempted to attach a screenshot from Mailchimp however I don't have enough reputation points right now! Thank you!

Comment: Sorry about the slow reply, I will try to snap something together tonight for you earn I get home from work. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you've provided for me, I've put the following PHP class together which should hopefully provide you with the functionality you need.  The bottom of the code demonstrates the usage of the small class.

```
<?php
class CSVtoSQL {
    private $filePath, $csvData;

    public function __construct($filePath) {
        $this->filePath = $filePath;
    }

    public function readDataIn() {
        $file = fopen($this->filePath, 'r');
        $data = fread($file, filesize($this->filePath));

        // Split CSV line by line.
        $lines = explode("\n", $data);

        // Split each line by commas to extract each value.
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($lines); $i++) {
            $this->csvData[$i] = explode(',', $lines[$i]);
        }

        fclose($file);

        // Returns true if we managed to read data, false if we didn't.
        return (sizeof($this->csvData) > 0);
    }

    public function getHeadings() {
        if (sizeof($this->csvData) > 0) {
            // The first index of csvData has all the headings.
            return $this->csvData[0];
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public function pushToDatabase($con, $tableName, $columns) {
        $createColumnQuery = '';
        $insertQuery = 'INSERT INTO ' . $tableName . ' (';

        // Build column section of query.
        foreach ($columns as $column) {
            $createColumnQuery .= $column['name'] . ' ' . $column['type'] . ',';
        }

        // Remove trailing comma.
        $createColumnQuery = rtrim($createColumnQuery, ',');

        // Create table.
        $con->query('CREATE TABLE ' . $tableName . ' (' . $createColumnQuery . ')');

        // Create insert query template.
        foreach ($columns as $column) {
            $insertQuery .= $column['name'] . ',';
        }

        // Remove trailing comma.
        $insertQuery = rtrim($insertQuery, ',');

        // Insert values using our insertQuery string which looks like: "INSERT INTO <<table name>> (<<column 1>>, <<column 2>>"
        // Also skip the first line as that has the headings.
        for ($i = 1; $i < sizeof($this->csvData); $i++) {
            $values = '';

            foreach($this->csvData[$i] as $value) {
                $values .= '\'' . $value . '\',';
            }

            // Remove trailing comma.
            $values = rtrim($values, ',');
            $con->query($insertQuery . ') VALUES (' . $values . ')');
        }
    }
}

$csv = new CSVtoSQL('test.csv');
$csv->readDataIn();
var_dump($csv->getHeadings());
$con = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'testdb');
$columns = array(array('name'=>'col1', 'type'=>'VARCHAR(256)'),
                array('name'=>'col2', 'type'=>'VARCHAR(256)'),
                array('name'=>'col3', 'type'=>'VARCHAR(256)'));
$csv->pushToDatabase($con, 'test_table', $columns);
?>
```

When creating a new object of the class CSVtoSQL, pass through the path to the CSV file (this can be relative or absolute).  Then call the readDataIn() procedure to open the CSV, pull out the lines and store them in the object.  Then you can optionally fetch an array of headings found in the CSV by calling getHeadings().  This will be useful for you when you wish to prompt the user for what database columns they wish to map each CSV heading to.  Lastly, call pushToDatabase() and provide a MySQLi connection object, a table name and column data, as demonstrated.

It's trivial for me to write the upload form for you, but this class should help solve your problem.

Good luck!

Comment: Shane, thank you! I appreciate your effort to make this work. I'm trying to utilize this now.

Comment: No worries, shouldn't be too difficult to implement with some simple HTML forms.  Good luck!